# React Native Camera is able to capture images but is NOT recording video

Tags: react-hooks, react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-video

I am trying to use react-native-camera package to create an app to take pictures and record videos.
I took the example code and converted it to functional component, since its necessary for my app. I am able to take pictures and store in local cache, but function for recording video is not working, and not showing any output when I console.log it. Do I need to implement stop recording also? I am new to react native and and I didn't find reference for functional implementation anywhere properly. I am confused regarding this. Below is the code, with two buttons, one for picture and one for video

```
...
import { RNCamera } from "react-native-camera";

const App = () => {
  let [flash, setFlash] = useState("off");
  let [zoom, setZoom] = useState(0);
  let [autoFocus, setAutoFocus] = useState("on");
  let [depth, setDepth] = useState(0);
  let [type, setType] = useState("back");
  let [permission, setPermission] = useState("undetermined");
  let [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState("false");
  let [recordingOptions, setRecordingOptions] = useState({
    mute: false,
    maxDuration: 10,
    quality: RNCamera.Constants.VideoQuality["360p"],
  });
  let cameraRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    Permissions.check("photo").then((response) => {
      // Response is one of: 'authorized', 'denied', 'restricted', or 'undetermined'
      setPermission(response);
    });
  }, []);

  const toggleFlash = () => {
    setFlash(flashModeOrder[flash]);
  };
  const zoomOut = () => {
    setZoom(zoom - 0.1 < 0 ? 0 : zoom - 0.1);
  };
  const zoomIn = () => {
    setZoom(zoom + 0.1 > 1 ? 1 : zoom + 0.1);
  };
  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (cameraRef) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);
      console.log(data.uri);
    }
  };

  const takeVideo = async () => {
    if (cameraRef && !isRecording) {
      try {
        console.log(recordingOptions);
        const recordoptions = {
          mute: false,
          maxDuration: 10,
          quality: RNCamera.Constants.VideoQuality["360p"],
        };
        const promise = cameraRef.current.recordAsync(recordOptions);

        if (promise) {
          setIsRecording(true);
          const data = await promise;
          console.log("takeVideo", data.uri);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RNCamera
        ref={cameraRef}
        style={styles.preview}
        type={type}
        flashMode={flash}
      />
      <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={takePicture} style={styles.capture}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> TAKE PICTURE </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={takeVideo} style={styles.capture}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> TAKE VIDEO </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor these lines

```
const promise = cameraRef.current.recordAsync(recordOptions);

if (promise) {
   setIsRecording(true);
   const data = await promise;
   console.log("takeVideo", data.uri);
}
```

To

```
setIsRecording(true);
const data = await cameraRef.current.recordAsync(recordOptions);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks, I tried this suggestion but it doesn't work. Still no video capture